# Search sub-directories using robocopy

Tags: powershell, robocopy, powershell-5.0

I wrote a quick robocopy script to search a directory and move video files that match certain criteria (size, name, extension). It works great except it will not search sub-directories. I tried the /s flag but that moves over the entire directory. I only want the files in those directories. Is there an easy way to plug the robocopy portion into a Get-Child or a loop in powershell? Thanks!

```
robocopy C:\psTesting\sourceDrive\ C:\psTesting\movieFolder\ *.mp4 *.avi *.mkv /min:600000000 /mov /np
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way that I can think is to make a function for it. This should do what you want:

```
Function PSRoboCopy{
[cmdletbinding()]
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipelinebyPropertyName=$True)]
    [Alias('SourceFile')]
    [String[]]$FullName,
    [string]$Destination,
    [string]$Options
)
Process{
    $FileIn = Split-Path $FullName -Leaf
    $FolderIn = Split-Path $FullName
    & robocopy $FolderIn $Destination $FileIn $Options
}
}

Get-ChildItem 'C:\psTesting\sourceDrive\*' -Include '*.mp4','*.avi','*.mkv' -Recurse | Where{$_.length -gt 600000000} | PSRoboCopy -Destination 'C:\psTesting\movieFolder\' -Options "/mov /np"
```

That lets you pipe a file object directly into it and specify your destination and any options you want.

Comment: This new function worked in the 'psTesting' folder but when I ran it on a network drive 'X:\*' it no longer searches the sub directories. Strange. Could it be a permissions issue?

Comment: Are you using `X:*` or `X:\*`? I'm not sure if it makes a difference, but usually driveletter-colon refers to the current folder on that drive, vs driveletter-colon-backslash referring to the root of the specified drive.